# how to speed up listing printers with powershell

Tags: windows-7, windows, powershell

When I use the following Powershell command to list all the printers my laptop has configured, it takes a few minutes for Windows to return the result. I have 3 printers configured, one is a virtual CutePDF printer, one is a Canon printer on my home network and the last is a Xerox printer on my work network.

I am currently using the following to list the printers

```
gwmi -class Win32_Printer -computer .
```

Are there faster ways to do this? What's causing the slow down, is it interrogating the network for print server?

Comment: I'm guessing it's trying to query the work printer and timing out eventually. On my computer that only has local and home network printers configured, the same command takes only 1-2 seconds.

Comment: That's my thought as well. I would think there would be some way to specify a timeout or have a little more control over the way you query for it. I guess I could go directly against the registry.

Comment: I found a PS function that wraps `Get-WmiObject` and allows you to specify the timeout: http://www.muscetta.com/2009/05/27/get-wmicustom. See if that fixes your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no workaround, since the `Win32_Printer` is the OS object.